# WAMP phpmyadmin error

Tags: php, wamp

I just installed WAMP server and for creating a new local database, when I clicked phpMyAdmin, i am getting this error,

Error

MySQL said: Documentation

## 1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.

Can some one please help me??

Answer (score 0):

you are connecting to your local machine. If i am correct wamp does not set any credentials. So you should be fine to login with root and no password.

Answer (score 0):

If you user has not password connect so. Try do it:

`mysql_connect('server','user');`

without thrid parameter. If all is right, you are connect to server.
else, if your user has password, you need provide the password correct

```
mysql_connect('server','user','password_correct');
```

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I have used WAMP (I only use Linux and OSX these days) I seem to remember the following...

In a command prompt enter in the mysql directory :

```
mysqladmin -u root password NEWPASSWORD
```

By default a mysql root password is not set yet the phpmyadmin pages are set to to connect with a password.

Dave